# How to setup a http(s) proxy with record/replay functionality?

Tags: android, ssl, https, proxy

The use case is:

I want to do some android app performance tests and I want to fix the data when app got from web.

The solution I come up with is to setup a local http proxy, which can first record all http traffic, and later replay then app is running perf tests.

I found http://mitmproxy.org/, which has exactly the features I want. but seems with the default settings it cannot be used as a https proxy. I tried using it as proxy and login to facebook but doesn't work.

I am not familiar with the https protocol and how cert things work. Any one can provide some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you accept the SSL certs or add exceptions for those  (since the SSL certificates that it returns will not be trusted and depending upon browser will toss errors..

Comment: @Doon, the request are sent from an android app and I didn't see any options to add exceptions (as the one I saw in firefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS proxy is very different from HTTP proxy - the proxy server receives CONNECT command and establishes opaque channel between the client and the server specified in parameter to CONNECT command. So you can't easily capture HTTPS traffic this way.

In general you can use HTTP proxy for HTTPS connection, in which case the proxy acts as an HTTP proxy and establishes SSL channel between the client and itself and between the server and itself. The proxy presents its own certificate (usually self-signed as such proixes are mainly used for development and monitoring purposes) to the client and validates the certificate of the remote server.

The above scheme requires that (a) the HTTP proxy can do this ("mitmproxy" suggests that it does), (b) that the client supports such configuration and (c) that proxy's certificate can be validated or trusted on the client.

I have some doubts that (b) and (c) are supported on Android.